# How to reprint a spool file using XPS printer?

Tags: c#, printing, print-spooler-api

I am building a program to capture printed documents and then convert these documents to xps\image.

Currently i am using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor the directory "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\" and copy the spl files, make sure its not duplicate then **try** converting it to xps file by printing the spl file using the [Win32 Spooler API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) and the *Microsoft XPS Document Writer* predefined printer, but when i specify an output file as shown below, the error code 1804 is returned, if i leave it empty it succeeds but then i don't get an output file.

```
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, string outputFile, string dataType, out int errorCode)
    {
        IntPtr hPrinter;
        var di = new DOCINFOA();
        var bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "Spool Doc";
        di.pDataType = dataType;
        di.pOutputFile = outputFile;

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    var dwWritten = 0;
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        errorCode = bSuccess == false ? Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() : 0;
        return bSuccess;
    }
```

So, what i am doing wrong, and how to print\convert the spool file to an XPS document, and if possible to an image file and a text file.

**Edit: Adding Additional info**

here is the implementation of DOCINFOA

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
    }
```

and here is the complete call chain:

The app runs the following code

```
    var dataTypes = new[] { null, "RAW", "RAW [FF appended]", "RAW [FF auto]", "NT EMF 1.003", "NT EMF 1.006", "NT EMF 1.007", "NT EMF 1.008", "TEXT", "XPS_PASS", "XPS2GDI" };
    foreach (var dataType in dataTypes)
    {
        int errorCode;
        RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(@"Microsoft XPS Document Writer", sourceFile, outputFile, dataType, out errorCode);
        //print errorCode
    }
```

And in *RawPrinterHelper*

```
    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName, string outputPath, string dataType, out int errorCode)
    {
        // Open the file.
        var fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        var documentPath = Path.GetFileName(szFileName);
        var nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        var bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        var pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        var bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength, outputPath, dataType, out errorCode);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        fs.Close();
        return bSuccess;
    }
```

And the API functions

```
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);
```

Comment: What are you setting pDataType to?  That's most likely the cause of the error.  Try setting it to null.  If that doesn't work, try "RAW".

Comment: @CareyGregory i tried these types  null, "RAW", "RAW [FF appended]", "RAW [FF auto]", "NT EMF 1.003", "NT EMF 1.006", "NT EMF 1.007", "NT EMF 1.008", "TEXT", "XPS_PASS", "XPS2GDI" in a loop and all gave the same error

Comment: Please add your declaration of DOCINFOA to your post.

Comment: @CareyGregory added, thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your declaration of the DOC_INFO_1 struct.  It doesn't match [the layout Windows expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The Windows declaration looks like this:

```
typedef struct _DOC_INFO_1 {
  LPTSTR pDocName;
  LPTSTR pOutputFile;
  LPTSTR pDatatype;
} DOC_INFO_1;
```

But your declaration has it like this:

```
public class DOCINFOA
{
    public string pDataType;
    public string pDocName;
    public string pOutputFile;
}
```

Reorder the elements in your declaration to match the Windows struct and it should fix your problem.

EDIT:  Bad news.  Your approach will not work.  Take a look at the documentation for [WritePrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> WritePrinter only supports GDI printing and must not be used for XPS
>   printing. If your print job uses the XPS or the OpenXPS print path,
>   [then use the XPS Print API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Sending XPS or OpenXPS print jobs to the
>   spooler using WritePrinter is not supported and can result in
>   undetermined results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the issue of the error code 1804, however the saved file at the output path is another spl file(mostly a copy) and not an XPS file, and a window still pops up to save the file, although it appears in a weird way with a message saying "a program can't display a message on your desktop", so can pOutputFile be used to specify the xps target location, and if not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: @MEYWD See the information I added to my answer.  I'm afraid you're going to have to redesign this.