# How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET and print a pdf file

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

I'm reading a pdf file attachment into memory and trying to send it to the printer.

I seem to be having an issue with the type of the document.

I'm creating an instance of DOCINFOA and I've been experimenting with the values for the data type parameter as described in this posting:
[How to reprint a spool file using XPS printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832708/how-to-reprint-a-spool-file-using-xps-printer)

However I'm not getting a print. The document appears on the print queue but then just disappears. I've tried all of the possibilities for data type, all those with RAW appear on the queue but nothing is ever printed.

I get a print using TEXT but its just nonsense, and all of the rest do nothing at all.

I'd like to know what the data type should be in order to print a pdf.

If I don't use the winapi functions and instead write the document to file and open it programatically using acrobt32, I get the print that I expect, but we want to avoid writing to disk.

I'm using code gleaned from this post:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-gb